# Term used for a feeling or dream of events happening in the short or near term.

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, vocabulary

They say Nostradamus could see the future. While not being so bold but what is the term used to describe when some people at times are able to dream or know what is going to happening in the short-term/near future and that actually happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nostradamus is sometime given credit for having **prophetic** abilities (or could render a **prophecy**) which is of a **longer term** predictive quality.

Shorter term accurate predictions might be described by:

> As a single word it is a **premonition**. It is often (but not always)
>   used in a negative forewarning sense.
>
> As an idiom or phrase it is a **sixth sense**. The idiom/phrase does
>   not carry any similar foreboding implication.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/premonition

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sixth+sense

Answer (score 1):

If it's a feeling, then the most appropriate term is probably:

> premonition
>   1. an intuition of a future, usually unwelcome, occurrence; foreboding
>  [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/premonition)

or

> precognition
>   1.(mass noun) Foreknowledge of an event, especially as a form of extrasensory perception.
>  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/precognition)

If it's in a dream or something seen, then I'd say the more appropriate term is:

> vision
>   4. a mystical or religious experience of seeing some supernatural event, person, etc:
>  [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/vision)

Answer (score 1):

**[Oneiromancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oneiromancy)**

> (from the Greek όνειροϛ oneiros, dream, and μαντεία manteia, prophecy) is a form of divination based upon dreams; it is a system of dream interpretation that uses dreams to predict the future.

**Diviner**: one who practices [divination](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divination)

> 1: the art or practice that seeks to foresee or foretell future events or discover hidden knowledge usually by the interpretation of omens or by the aid of supernatural powers 
> 2: unusual insight : intuitive perception

**[Soothsayer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soothsayer)**

> : a person who predicts the future by magical, intuitive, or more rational means

**[Psychic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/psychic)**

> 2: lying outside the sphere of physical science or knowledge : immaterial, moral, or spiritual in origin or force 
>
>
> 3: sensitive to nonphysical or supernatural forces and influences : marked by extraordinary or mysterious sensitivity, perception, or understanding

Answer (score 1):

You could say that such a person is ***prescient***.  The Oxford Dictionaries define it as:

> ***[prescient](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prescient)***
>
> **ADJECTIVE**
>
> Having or showing knowledge of events before they take place.
>
> *‘a prescient warning’*

For example, when Donald Trump managed to get the UN laughing at him, I noted one of his tweets from 2014 where he said "We need a President who isn't a laughing stock to the entire World[sic]" and asked if perhaps he wasn't *prescient*.